# Java annotation not working on Callable

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I have writen an annotation (in a spring boot application) and try to apply it to the `call()` method of `Callable`, but it doesn't work, yet on the other hand, when applied to a normal method (please see code below), it works, this keeps bothering me, could you please give me some clues? Thank you very much.

Here are my code,

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class LogExecutionTimeAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExecutionTimeAspect.class);

    @Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        final long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        logger.info(joinPoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
        return proceed;
    }
}


public class DummyCallable implements Callable<Integer> {

    private Integer start, count;

    DummyCallable() {}

    DummyCallable(Integer start, Integer count) {
        this.start = start;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @LogExecutionTime // not working...
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(start * 1000);
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer i = start; i <= start + count; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}



@LogExecutionTime // This will work... 
public List<Integer> getAllUserScores() {
    Callable c1 = new DummyCallable(1, 100000);
    Callable c2 = new DummyCallable(2, 100000);
    Callable c3 = new DummyCallable(3, 100000);
    // .... run them ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Spring uses proxies, only method calls INTO the object are intercepted, you are internally calling a method.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @sbjavateam, I realize that three things,

1. `spring aop work only with object that are managed by spring container. To apply aspect for your class it should be a bean or component and instantiated by spring context.`  (All right, this is copied from @sbjavateam's answer.)
2. Based on the former statement, `Callable c1 = new DummyCallable(1, 100000);` is wrong by nature, since we must create the `DummyCallable` from the spring context (so that bean will be properly injected with it's dependencies), calling `new` is not capable.
3. The `DummyCallable` class needs to have a scope of prototype so that it is not a singleton. The singleton scope is the default scope for a Spring bean. As a result, this class must have this annotation: `@Scope("prototype")`.

Below is my fix,

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DummyCallable implements Callable<Integer> {}


private DummyCallable createDummyCallable(Integer start, Integer end) {
        return context.getBean(DummyCallable.class, start, end);
    }
```

Besides, you might want this configuration as well,

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

Last but not least, thank you very much, @sbjavateam.

Comment: some remark , about point 2: you can apply aspect for this call without spring aop , you can apply ascpect to not managed bean by container , but you need compile your project with speial agent. AspectJ can be used during compile time or during classloading. Spring aop support aspectj , so if you compiled project with agent spring aop will support this call/. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw